# The mesh does not move and link with the bones ( armature )

Tags: mesh, armature, bones, pose-mode

i select the armature (object mode) --> s[image] shift +select mesh (abject mode) --> ctrl + p --> automatic weight ( pose mode )

i active the (deform) / (rigging: rigify  from prefrence)

Comment: Hello could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/